# /usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied for nodejs using AWS Code Deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, forever, aws-code-deploy

I wrote a script for deploying code to EC2 instance using AWS Code Deploy, my files are getting copied to the destination, then my hooks run, remove commands, cd commands are running fine but when the following command is run:

```
/usr/bin/node/bin/forever start /home/ubuntu/codebase/app/bin/www
```

I get the following error and deployment fails:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied
```

I have setup the node version v4.4.0 by downloading using wget and then adding following paths to bashrc:

```
export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/share/nodejs/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$NODEJS_HOME
```

I also added a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/nodejs/
```

My appspec.yml hooks:

```
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 30
      runas: ubuntu
```

Questions:

1. Why am I getting 'node: permission denied' error?
2. Secondly, Why I need to give the full path for 'npm, node, forever'?

If I go to the corresponding directory: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/..... and then run my script manually as an Ubuntu user, it works fine. Although running it as sudo, gives the same error on console

Comment: What happens when you change the runas : root? Also what are the permission on file start_server.sh?

Comment: same error. Permission denied.

Comment: If I go to the corresponding directory: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/..... and then run my script manually as an Ubuntu user, it works fine. Although running it as sudo, gives the same error on console.

Answer (score 0):

The service command strips out most of environment variables. So the variables NODEJS_HOME will not be available to start_server.sh. You can try and setting up the environment variables in /etc/profile. The agent sources that at startup.

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Amartya Datta Gupta